# Alternative to core data in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, server

I am building a social media application which requires local storage of table data entities. This data must also be connected to a server to retrieve and update information to and from users. Our team has built an iOS client using core data, though we are looking for storage options in android. Is using SQLite the way to go? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [Realm](https://realm.io/), it has clients for Objective-C, Swift and Android.

Description from their GitHub repository:

**Features**

**Mobile-first:** Realm is the first database built from the ground up to run directly inside phones, tablets and wearables.

**Simple:** Data is directly exposed as objects and queryable by code, removing the need for ORM's riddled with performance & maintenance issues. Plus, we've worked hard to keep our API down to very few classes: most of our users pick it up intuitively, getting simple apps up & running in minutes.

**Modern:** Realm supports easy thread-safety, relationships & encryption.

**Fast:** Realm is faster than even raw SQLite on common operations, while maintaining an extremely rich feature set.

---

If you're familiar with **RxJava**, you will probably want to check [SQLBrite](https://corner.squareup.com/2015/02/sqlbrite-reactive-sqlite-for-android.html), wich is Square's solution for this.

Comment: Say Rodrigo - what do you think about the Realm vs. Android's own ContentProvider?  I realize they're quite different, and it's a big question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Sqlite is a default storage solution for android. Howevere there is a wrap around it called [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html). `ContentProvider` can be used with [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) and provide async data loading. `ContentProvider` may be used to modify contats and merge accounts, see [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html). However `ContentProvider` may seem tricky and if you prefer ORMs you can use [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) or [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) which are using sqlite as well.